# How to set cookie for close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I want to set cookie when the button close is pressed to prevent the dialog box to open again.

This is my code:

```
<div class="card">
  <span class="clickable" data-effect="fadeOut"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
    <div class="card-blockquote">Free shipping </div>
</div>

<script>
jQuery('.close-icon').on('click',function() {
  jQuery(this).closest('.card').fadeOut();
})
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

I add this library:

```
<action method="addLinkRel"><rel>text/javascript</rel><href>https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.2/js.cookie.js</href></action>
```

and I use the following code:

```
 $.cookie('card', 'card', { expires: 7 });
```

and I have in console:

```
TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cookie generators. [here](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/04/j-is-for-jcookies-http-cookie-handling-for-jquery/)

```
<script>
jQuery('.close-icon').on('click',function() {
  jQuery(this).closest('.card').fadeOut();
$.jCookies({
    name : 'Your_cookie_Namee',
    value : {cookie values}
});

})
</script>
```

So if you want to use localstorage, you can use [this](https://github.com/fgiasson/jquery-enhanced-cookie)

Comment: Thank you but I prefer to use Local Storage or jquery cookies

Comment: @StefanD. use [this](https://github.com/fgiasson/jquery-enhanced-cookie)

Comment: How I can set the cookie for 1 day for example for my code? in fact what is name : 'Your_cookie_Namee', and value : {cookie values}